# Publish Content Broker DB in tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I am using SDL Tridion 2011 I want to know how to get the  content published to Broker DB (SQL database) and binary assets (Images, Flash, CSS & JS) get published to filestream.

We have looked and tried to modify cd_storage_conf.xml
 and found the below for file system

```
<Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Type="filesystem" Id="defaultDataFile"
 defaultFilesystem="false"><Root Path=" C:\applications\WebName\Publising_Data"/>
```

So similarly how the refernce to Brocker DB can be made, we are using SQL Database

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest you to read how to configure storage from this [link](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_005JJFGGGD8858699HHFHJF) (Login required) first and then come come with specific question/problem.

You may also search this over Google, you can find many articles about same.

Use following storage types for SQL server and file system

```
<Storage Type="filesystem" Id="LocalFileSystem_01" defaultFilesystem="true" defaultStorage="true"
  Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory">
  <Root Path="STORAGE_PATH" />
</Storage>
```

And then define the item type as per your requirement, here default is SQL server and I have override the for binary and pages to filesystem

```
 <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="CACHE_BEHAVIOR" storageId="LocalFileSystem_01" />
<Item typeMapping="Binary" itemExtension=".EXT" cached="CACHE_BEHAVIOR" storageId="LocalFileSystem_01" />

</ItemTypes>
```

Comment: Hi @vikas-kumar

I just wanted to know the xml node to be used to publish content to DB,
I don't have access to the link

Comment: @b00tbu9 I have updated the answer. Let me know if you need any thing else.

Comment: As a customer/partner you have access to that website, just contact customer support for the login information.